# "The name does not exist" error when switching target platform from AnyCPU to x86

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013, target-platform

I am building a WPF project on VS2013 Community. I wanted to use `CefSharp` in the project, but it cannot run on `AnyCPU` build configuration, so I changed it to `x86`. After that MainWindow.xaml.cs started throwing `The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context` and 25 more errors saying that none of my XAML control's names can be found. When I change to `x64` it's the same. When I return to `AnyCPU` the project compiles and runs perfectly.

So what else do I need to change in the configuration in order to make it work?

EDIT: I finally decided to drop CefSharp and returned the AnyCPU option everywhere. Now VS gives me the same errors only when building for Release. I reverted to the last stable version of the project in Git, but the errors won't go away. I've looked at Debug/Release settings in `Configuration manager` and `Project properties`, but everything seems fine. Is there somewhere else to look for Release settings?

Comment: Does all the errors go away after you do a clean then rebuild?

Comment: No. I tried that, but nothing changes. Restarting VS also has no effect.

Comment: You are surely changing the wrong setting.  Don't mess with the build configuration, you must use Project + Properties, Build tab, Target platform setting.

Comment: If I run on `AnyCPU` `CefSharp` throws this error: `Error CefSharp.Common does not work correctly on 'AnyCPU' platform. You need to specify platform (x86 / x64).`
And it seems that Project->Properties->Build settings are overrided by the selected build configuration. Even if I change the Target platform it switches back automatically to match the build configuration specified one, so it does not resolve the CefSharp error :(