# Cannot find XAML element names in code behind on Release

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2013

As described in [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30710557/the-name-does-not-exist-error-when-switching-target-platform-from-anycpu-to-x8) my problem started with `CefSharp` wanting to explicitly select platform `x86` or `x64`. This resulted in several errors where in code behind none of the `XAML` elements could be found, including `InitializeComponent();`. I removed `CefSharp` and set to `AnyCPU` again. Now `Debug` mode works perfectly, but when I switch to `Release` again the same erros occur.

What could be different between the two modes? Where do I look to fix these errors?

```
Error   The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context d:\visual studio\projects 2013\solutionname\projectname\ui\mainwindow.xaml.cs
Error   The name 'MenuItemAutoLogin' does not exist in the current context d:\visual studio\projects 2013\solutionname\projectname\ui\mainwindow.xaml.cs
Error   The name 'MenuItemAutoLogin' does not exist in the current context d:\visual studio\projects 2013\solutionname\projectname\ui\mainwindow.xaml.cs
Error   The name 'treeViewNotes' does not exist in the current context d:\visual studio\projects 2013\solutionname\projectname\ui\mainwindow.xaml.cs
Error   The name 'treeViewNotes' does not exist in the current context  d:\visual studio\projects 2013\solutionname\projectname\ui\mainwindow.xaml.cs
```

*Both `MainWindow.xaml` and `MainWindow.xaml.cs` are in `Project_Namescape.UI` subnamespace if it matters

EDIT: Deleting the `Obj` folder + `Clean` + `Rebuild` does not fix the errors.

Comment: delete the Obj folder manually and rebuild your application

Comment: I deleted the `Obj` folder and did `Clean` + `Rebuild`, but it's still the same.

Comment: If you are using a lot of different projects in your solution I highly recommend to check the build order of your projects and remove unnecessary dependencies. This was helping me once I had this issue in the past.

Comment: The project in the solution is just one. But I do have some 3rd party libraries I am using. Do you think it could be something related to them?

Comment: Since your debug mode is working, try deleting Release config and duplicating Debug and then switch the new profile's mode manually to release mode and add optimizations by yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all the error was my own. I had a third party dll in the solution directly referenced from the `Debug` folder. Even though the `CopyLocal` was set to `True` the dll was not automatically copied in the `Release` folder.

Now I've moved the dll in the `Resources` folder and re-referenced it. Everything works perfectly.